# Watchdog on cloud based server and database?

Tags: server, cloud, database, watchdog

I am running a cloud based server and two database. I have python scripts that connects to the databases and moves data between them. When the cloud databases have been updated or outages, the connections have been lost and the scripts have continued to run but without working properly.

I will look into the scripts themselves, but I have been wanting to implement some monitoring to be able to restart the scripts when a connection is lost.

I am new to system monitoring and is why I ask this question. What is the standard solution to this? Is there any recommended/standard software for this particular case?